How does the SMAP satellite cope with conflicting gyroscopic forces?
The SMAP is a synthetic aperture radar Earth observation satellite in a 8-day exact repeat sun synchronous orbit.




This a beautiful animation of the satellite deployment
https://smap.jpl.nasa.gov/resources/83/smap-antenna-deployment-animation/?category=images
The satellite has two halves which rotate in relation to each other: the antenna/reflector and the bus. The antenna rotates around the zenith/nadir axis every scan cycle and the bus rotates around the orbital axis each orbit. If that wasn’t enough, the orbital axis needs to precess once a year.
The relatively rapid rotation of the antenna structure is reminiscent of a spin-stabilized spacecraft, so it should oppose the other rotations.
How are these gyroscopic forces  managed?

I believe at least one of these two papers https://arc.aiaa.org/doi/epdf/10.2514/6.2013-4560 https://arc.aiaa.org/doi/epdf/10.2514/6.2014-1304 will contain something illuminating, though they are both paywalled. E-mailing the authors might get copies though.  https://descanso.jpl.nasa.gov/NEDSummary/SMAP_20161024.pdf#%5B%7B%22num%22%3A106%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22XYZ%22%7D%2C69%2C636%2C0%5D section 2.1.2 at least mentions the actuators in the GNC system and is free.

@ErinAnne ... section 2.1.2 was very helpful. Reaction wheels do the heavy lifting and magnetorquers desaturate the reaction wheels.

Yeah, I didn't really think it quite told the whole story, but it does tell a lot of the story.  Here's another bit:  this paper doing a Monte Carlo analysis (no real detail) is determining if there's enough propellant to both do initial orbit acquisition and then orbit maintenance / attitude control (thruster desat I guess) for SMAP https://issfd.org/ISSFD_2012/ISSFD23_FDOP2_3_abstract.pdf
